# Plot a character on R instead of a point

Tags: r, data-visualization

I want to plot the coordinates

```
X = c(1,2,3)
Y = c(4,5,6)
```

but I want to have the custom characters

```
chr = c("A","B","C")
```

instead of points on the plot. That is, I want to have the letter "A" at location [1,4]. How do I do this in R?

Comment: If you are just plotting characters, do `plot(X, Y, pch=chr)`. Also this is wrong forum to ask questions of this sort. I am voting to move it to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. It's immediate using `ggplot2`'s `geom_text`:

```
library(ggplot2)
X = c(1,2,3)
Y = c(4,5,6)

chr = c("A","B","C")

df <- data.frame(X, Y, chr)

ggplot(df) + geom_text(aes(x = X, y = Y, label = chr))
```